# Sharepoint CAML Date query

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss, caml

im getting different results based on the date i use to search on.

Here are the 3 records i want to display, their values for EVENTDATE, and ENDDATE are as follows

```
1, 2009-08-11T00:00:00Z, 2009-08-14T23:59:59Z
2, 2009-08-11T00:00:00Z, 2009-08-14T23:59:59Z
3, 2009-08-14T20:00:00Z, 2009-08-14T22:00:00Z
```

When i search for a time between EventDate and EndDate

```
- 2009-08-14T20:00:00Z, 2009-08-14T22:00:00Z
= i get rows 1,2

-  2009-08-14 T20:00:00Z, 2009-08-14 T22:00:00Z
= i get rows 3
```

Why does adding a space between  the date and time give me a diff result? The entries into the list are the same, the return results dates are the exact same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the [ISO 8601 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) specifies that a space to either side of the T is valid, I would guess that the CAML parser only accepts non spaces. And what you are seeing is a side effect.